# Python Pandas convert column data type

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I know a question like this has been asked zillion types, but so far I have not been able to find an answer to this question.

I have joined two .csv files together with Pandas and now I would like to add some more columns to the new joined .csv file and the values calculate based on the already available data.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
"The truth value of a is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
```

Now that obviously seems to be a problem with the data type of my column (which is all integers), but I have not found a (working) way to set that column as integers.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas

def nscap(ns):
    if ns <= 13:
        x = ns
    elif ns > 13:
        x = 13
    return x

df_1 = pandas.read_csv("a.csv", sep=';', names=["DWD_ID", "NS"], header=0)
df_2 = pandas.read_csv("b.csv", sep=';', names=["VEG", "DWD_ID"], header=0)
df_joined = pandas.merge(df_1, df_2, on="DWD_ID")
df_joined["NS_Cap"] = nscap(df_joined["NS"])
```

If i set

```
df_joined["NS_Cap"] = nscap(20)
```

the code works fine

I have tried functions like .astype(int) or .to_numeric() but unless I had the syntax wrong, it didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. IIUYC, you want to *apply* `nscap` against the `NS` column to get `NS_Cap`, am I correct?

Comment: You're after `df_joined['NS_Cap'] = df_joined['NS'].clip_upper(13)` see: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip_upper.html there error here is that you're trying to compare an array using an operator that understand scalar values, if you did `df_joined['NS'].apply(nscap)` then it should work

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thank you so much! So far never came across that syntax before!

Comment: Hi, a new question requires a new post. If any of the answers satisfy/ies your original question, kindly upvote/accept it. Just leave a link here to your new post/question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with @EdChum's comment, you need to use `clip(upper=13)` or `clip_upper(13)`. One other option which can help you in the long run with instances like this is to use `apply` with a lambda function. This is a really nifty all-around method.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5,18,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
nscap = lambda x: min(x, 13)

print df.head()
print '-' * 20

df['NSCAP'] = df['D'].apply(nscap)

print df.head()
```

Result:

[image]

Take note of the last 2 lines of the second dataframe.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer. Note that `apply` + lambda is usually much slower than the vectorized functions, so `clip_upper` is probably better.

Comment: I tried both options and yes they both seem much faster than what I was trying before. So that clip_upper(xy) does not only stop counting onwards from that number but also sets every number that is higher to also that number?

Comment: @Khaled Exactly. You are technically setting an upper bound and *clipping* whatever comes after that.

Answer (score 1):

(Your code is missing a parenthesis at the end of `nscap(df_joined["NS"]`.)

As @EdChum and @TheLaughingMan write, `clip_upper` is what you want here. This answer just addresses the direct reason for the error you're getting.

In the function

```
def nscap(ns):
    if ns <= 13:
        x = ns
    elif ns > 13:
        x = 13
    return x
```

effectively, `ns <= 13` operations on a `numpy.ndarray`. When you compare such an array to a scalar, broadcasting takes place, and the result is an array where each element indicates whether it was true for it or not.

So

```
if ns <= 13:
```

translates to something like

```
if numpy.array([True, False, True, True]):
```

and it's impossible to understand whether this is true or not. That's the error you're getting: you need to specify whether you mean if *all* entries are true, if *some* entry is true, and so on.