# Calculate a new column with Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39698097/6618225) Question, I would like to know how can I use a def() to calculate a new column with Pandas and use more than one arguments (strings and integers)?

Concrete example:

```
df_joined["IVbest"] = IV(df_joined["Saison"], df_joined["Wald_Typ"], df_joined["NS_Cap"])
```

"Saison", "Wald_Typ" are strings "NS_Cap" is an integer

Now I want to run all those values through this definition and return me again an x-value:

```
def IV(saison, wald, ns):
    if saison == "Sommer":
        if wald == "Laubwald":
            x = ns * 0.1
        elif wald == "Nadelwald":
            x = ns * 0.2
        elif wald == "Mischwald":
            x = ns * 0.3
    elif saison == "Winter":
        if wald == "Laubwald":
            x = ns * 0.01
        elif wald == "Nadelwald":
            x = ns * 0.02
        elif wald == "Mischwald":
            x = ns * 0.03
    return x
```

How would I accomplish that best?

I have tried stuff like

```
df_joined["IVbest"] = IV(df_joined["Saison", "Wald_Typ", "NS_Cap"])
```

or

```
df_joined["IVbest"] = df_joined["Saison", "Wald_Typ", "NS_Cap"].apply(IV)
```

but nothing works :(

Comment: You need to pass `axis=1` to `apply`: `df_joined["IVbest"] = df_joined[["Saison", "Wald_Typ", "NS_Cap"]].apply(lambda x: IV(x["Saison"], x["Wald_Typ"], x["NS_Cap"]), axis=1)`

Comment: Your `def` could work if you changed the signature to be just `def IV(df): #do stuff with df['saison'], df['wald'] and df['ns']` return a Series`

Comment: Thanks Ed! Your first example works well. What if I want the output to be an integer? Can I apply something like int(round(xy)) to the output? I will definately look into your other idea too!

Comment: that may work but the general principle here is to avoid using loops and `apply`, you should be able to perform your operation on the df using vectorised methods which operate on the entire df but we don't know because you've not posted your full code

Comment: ok, I have posted my def(). any ideas? Sorry for all those many questions lately, but I am very new to Pandas and this module seems to be quite complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case it would be better to use 6 masks and use these to perform the calculations just on those rows:

```
sommer_laub = (df_joined['Saison'] == 'Sommer') & (df_joined['Wald_Typ'] == 'Laubwald')
sommer_nadel = (df_joined['Saison'] == 'Sommer') & (df_joined['Wald_Typ'] == 'Nadelwald')
sommer_misch = (df_joined['Saison'] == 'Sommer') & (df_joined['Wald_Typ'] == 'Mischwald')
winter_laub = (df_joined['Saison'] == 'Winter') & (df_joined['Wald_Typ'] == 'Laubwald')
winter_nadel = (df_joined['Saison'] == 'Winter') & (df_joined['Wald_Typ'] == 'Nadelwald')
winter_misch = (df_joined['Saison'] == 'Winter') & (df_joined['Wald_Typ'] == 'Mischwald')
df.loc[sommer_laub, 'IVbest'] = df.loc[sommer_laub,'NS_Cap'] * 0.1
df.loc[sommer_nadel, 'IVbest'] = df.loc[sommer_nadel,'NS_Cap'] * 0.2
df.loc[sommer_misch, 'IVbest'] = df.loc[sommer_misch,'NS_Cap'] * 0.3
df.loc[winter_laub, 'IVbest'] = df.loc[winter_laub,'NS_Cap'] * 0.01
df.loc[winter_nadel, 'IVbest'] = df.loc[winter_nadel,'NS_Cap'] * 0.02
df.loc[winter_misch, 'IVbest'] = df.loc[winter_misch,'NS_Cap'] * 0.03
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this way. But why is it better? Faster or just more elegant?

Comment: Faster, this will work on just the rows of interest for each mask, your method would require looking at each row and evaluating your boolean conditions separately which would be slower for a large df

Comment: Large it is, and getting more and more the more complex the data pool grows. So faster is good :-)