# Calculating a new column in Python with Pandas and different Input and output types

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

The 3rd and hopefully last type of these questions is as following.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39703749/6618225) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39698097/6618225) Question, how would I create calculate and calculate a new column in Pandas where the input is an integer and a range and the output a string?

This is my original definition as I had it in ArcPY:

```
def Gefaehrdestufe(staok_klasse, nFK):
    x = ""
    if staok_klasse == 1:
        if nFK in range(0, 36):
            x = "Geringes Risiko"
        elif nFK in range(36, 51):
            x = "Geringes Risiko"
        elif nFK in range (51, 66):
            x = "Geringes Risiko"
        elif nFK in range(66, 86):
            x = "Gering bis mäßig"
        elif nFK >= 86:
            x = "Mäßig"
    elif staok_klasse == 2:
        if nFK in range(0, 36):
            x = "Geringes Risiko"
        elif nFK in range(36, 51):
            x = u"Gering bis mäßig"
        elif nFK in range (51, 66):
            x = u"Gering bis mäßig"
        elif nFK in range(66, 86):
            x = u"Mäßig"
        elif nFK >= 86:
            x = u"Mäßig hoch"
    return x
```

I have tried with .apply():

```
df_joined["Gef_Stufe"] = df_joined["StaokKlass", "nFK"].apply(Gefaehrdestufe)
```

and with the method mentioned in one of my other questions:

```
st_1_nfk_0_36 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] in range(0,36))
st_1_nfk_36_51 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] in range(36, 51))
st_1_nfk_51_66 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] in range(51, 66))
st_1_nfk_66_85 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] in range(66, 85))
st_1_nfk_85_x = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] >= 86)      
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_0_36, "Gef_stufe"] = "Geringes Risiko"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_36_51, "Gef_stufe"] = "Geringes Risiko"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_51_66, "Gef_stufe"] = "Geringes Risiko"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_66_85, "Gef_stufe"] = u"Gering bis mäßig"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_85_x, "Gef_stufe"] = u"Mäßig"
```

also with this style:

```
st_1_nfk_0_36 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] > 0) & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"] < 36)
```

But none worked.

**EDIT:**

So I have updated my code to @EdChum 's suggestions but I keep getting this error: `exceptions.TypeError: invalid type comparison`.
Now for testing purposes I have taken the first half of the condition out `(df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1")` and the code runs through without error, however it does not give me the desired (or any) output. So the problem is definately in this part but I cannot figure out why. I have tried with and without brackets but every time the same error.
`df_joined.info()` confirms that the column `df_joined["Staokklass"]` is an integer and nFK is a float.

```
st_1_nfk_0_36 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(0,36))))
st_1_nfk_36_51 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(36, 51))))
st_1_nfk_51_66 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(51, 66))))
st_1_nfk_66_85 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1") & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(66, 85))))
 & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(86,1000))))      

df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_0_36, "Gef_stufe"] = "Geringes Risiko"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_36_51, "Gef_stufe"] = "Geringes Risiko"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_51_66, "Gef_stufe"] = "Geringes Risiko"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_66_85, "Gef_stufe"] = u"Gering bis mäßig"
df_joined.loc[st_1_nfk_85_x, "Gef_stufe"] = u"Mäßig"
```

So question 1: How do I have to change the first condition to be accepted and
question 2: I want Python to create me a new column `df_joined[Gef_Stufe]` that has the string declarations (preferably with the unicode characters).

One more thing: I would like the last condition to be like `>= 86` instead of `range(0, 1000)`, while that would do the job because the ranges will never be that high. But out of curiosity and learning purposes (and a clean code) I would like to know how I could accomplish that.

**EDIT 2:**

Here the output for df_joined.info() and df_joined.dtypes:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 63117 entries, 0 to 63116
Data columns (total 38 columns):
OBJECTID      63117 non-null int64
FORSTAMT      63117 non-null int64
REVIER        63117 non-null int64
ABTEILUNG     63117 non-null int64
LAND          63117 non-null object
VEG           63117 non-null int64
Ortsname      63117 non-null object
DWD_ID        63117 non-null object
ForstortID    63117 non-null object
nFK_staok     63117 non-null int64
Wald_Typ      63117 non-null object
Datum         63117 non-null datetime64[ns]
nFK           63117 non-null int64
NS            63117 non-null int64
NV            63117 non-null float64
NS_Prog_1     63117 non-null int64
NS_Prog_2     63117 non-null int64
NS_Prog_3     63117 non-null int64
FET           63117 non-null int64
NS_Cap        63117 non-null int64
NS_Cap_P1     63117 non-null int64
NS_Cap_P2     63117 non-null int64
NS_Cap_P3     63117 non-null int64
Monat         63117 non-null object
Saison        63117 non-null object
IVbest        63117 non-null float64
NVbest        63117 non-null float64
nFK_140       63117 non-null float64
NV_Prog_1     63117 non-null float64
NV_Prog_2     63117 non-null float64
NV_Prog_3     63117 non-null float64
IV_Prog_1     63117 non-null float64
IV_Prog_2     63117 non-null float64
IV_Prog_3     63117 non-null float64
nFK_Prog      63117 non-null float64
nFK_ges       63117 non-null float64
nFK_Proz      63117 non-null float64
StaokKlass    63117 non-null int64

dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(13), int64(17), object(7)
memory usage: 17.1+ MB
```

The df_joined["StaokKlass"] column consists of numbers (integers) from 1 to 6 and is then divided into each ranges from 0 to 36, to 55 and so on (that is df_joined["Gef_stufe"]

Comment: `in` won't work with arrays use `isin`: `df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(0,36)))`

Comment: Gets me this error `exceptions.TypeError: invalid type comparison`. What about the parts `> 86`? Can those work or is there another way tell Python "86 and higher"?

Comment: that should work unless your dtype is not numeric what does `df_joined.info()` show?

Comment: Shows me this:
`nFK           63117 non-null int64
StaokKlass    63117 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(13), int64(17), object(7)
memory usage: 17.1+ MB`

Comment: I just found that the problem must be in the part ´(df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1")´of my code. When I remove that code for test purposes the program runs through.

Comment: Definately there is the problem behind it. When I try to run `df_joined["StaokKlass"] == "1"` as the argument, it doesn't work again. The field "StaokKlass" is defined as INT but cannot even run alone.

Comment: Now I noticed that the code may run through without error message (though without the Staokklasse == statement, but yet I don't get the string-output as in "Geringes Risiko" and so on. The values are simply left blank. So that doesn't work yet either.

Comment: @EdChum: would be really nice if you could check out my code problem. You seem to exactly know how to solve my problems, so if you looked into it another time, i'd be eternally grateful :D

Comment: If StaokKlass is dtype int why are you comparing with a string? shouldn't it be `df_joined["StaokKlass"] == 1`? i.e. without quotes around 1

Comment: @EdChum That was my original solution. That doesn't get my an error message (neither does with ""), but i get no output at all ("Geringes Risiko" and stuff)

Comment: @EdChum, sorry to bother you with this topic. I promise there are only 2 more columns left (including this one here) and the last one I should be able to solve that myself hopefully. I just need to finish this program asap because I have to present it in 2 weeks and still run several tests on it. I would highly appreciate it if you (or anyone for that matter) could help me solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you edit your question with the output from `df.info()` and `df.dtypes` also I can't help unless I have your data and code

Comment: @EdChum I added the information. Do you need anything else?

Comment: Well one problem I can see is that nFK_Proz is dtype float so trying to compare floats with ints is not going to work or may not wor how you think so I think you may have to change the comparison from `df_joined["nFK_Proz"].isin(list(range(0,36)))` to `df_joined["nFK_Proz"].between(0, 36)` and so on, can you try that

Comment: @EdChum that helped a little. Now the first values like "Maessig" are being set. For some weird reason ONLY to the case when `df_joined["StaokKlass"] == 1`and regardless of `df_joined["nFK_Proz"]`get assigned all the type of values, to "Hoch" and "Maessig-hoch", although those values do not even exist for StaokKlass == 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution! The problem was a wrong bracket in the first expression of the conditions.

I had 
`st_1_nfk_0_36 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"]) == 1 & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].between(0,36))`

when it should have been

`st_1_nfk_0_36 = (df_joined["StaokKlass"] == 1) & (df_joined["nFK_Proz"].between(0,36))`

So now it works fine and I get my wanted output! Thanks so much! Hopefully the final column goes without problems :-D

Answer (score 0):

***Option 1***

```
data = {
    1: [
        (u'Geringes Risiko', 66),
        (u'Gering bis mäßig', 86),
        (u'Mäßig',),
    ],    
    2: [
        (u'Geringes Risiko', 51),
        (u'Gering bis mäßig', 66),
        (u'Mäßig', 86),
        (u'Mäßig hoch',),
    ],    
}

def Gefaehrdestufe(staok_klasse, nFK):
    for group in data[staok_klasse][:-1]:
        if nFK < group[1]:
            return group[0]
    return data[staok_klasse][-1][0]
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but for me as quite a Python beginner quite ununderstandable. I will look into it. Is that meant for Pandas?